# Raw String Python Alternative?

Tags: python, string, tkinter, xlrd

I am trying to read in an excel file using xlrd and use tkinter to find the file. I am having trouble with the \ operator. If I would hard code the file path I could use the raw string command, r'filepath'. Is there something similar I could use, like, r(filepath) to convert the string to a raw string? My code and the error is listed below,

```
import xlrd
from tkinter import Tk, filedialog, messagebox

application_window = Tk()
application_window.withdraw()

messagebox.showinfo("Information", "Select the Layout")
path = filedialog.askopenfilenames(title="Layout")

Layout = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
```

Error:

File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd__init__.py", line 395, in open_workbook with open(filename, "rb") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "('filepath',)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as a raw-string within a running Python interpreter. raw-strings are only useful for written Python-Code to make it easier for programmers to enter otherwise escaped characters - most notably back-slashes that are also used in regular expressions as escape characters themselves.

Your problem is different: you think you get a path from askopenfilename. But what you get is a `tuple` with a number of paths, in your case just one.

So just use `tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename` without the trailing s to get just one.

Comment: Yep this solved my problem. Thank you for your help and your insight.

Comment: @Akkarris then mark the answer as solving your problem if you don't mind :)